# Silverback messages not published to the correct Kafka Topic

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I am using the library [Silverback](https://silverback-messaging.net) and Apache Kafka as the message broker.

I have a two message classes:

- Animal (base class) which is published to / consumed from the "animals" Kafka topic
- Dog (extends Animal, but doesn't have any additional property) which is published to / consumed from the "dogs" Kafka topic

When I publish the message of type Dog, Silverback publishes one message in "animals" and another message in "dogs".

I was expecting the message of type Dog to be published only on the "dogs" topic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you've gotten your answer here https://github.com/BEagle1984/silverback/issues/183#issuecomment-1411969511